# Python Pandas totals and dates

Tags: python, pandas, graph

Im sorry for not posting the data but it wouldn't really help. The thing is a need to make a graph and I have a csv file full of information organised by date. It has 'Cases' 'Deaths' 'Recoveries' 'Critical' 'Hospitalized' 'States' as categories. It goes in order by date and has the amount of cases,deaths,recoveries per day of each state. How do I sum this categories to make a graph that shows how the total is increasing? I really have no idea how to start so I can't post my data. Below are some numbers that try to explain what I have.

```html
0    2020-02-20        1   Andalucía     NaN             NaN    NaN   
1    2020-02-20        2      Aragón     NaN             NaN    NaN   
2    2020-02-20        3    Asturias     NaN             NaN    NaN   
3    2020-02-20        4    Baleares     1.0             NaN    NaN   
4    2020-02-20        5    Canarias     1.0             NaN    NaN   
..          ...      ...         ...     ...             ...    ...   
888  2020-04-06       19     Melilla    92.0            40.0    3.0   
889  2020-04-06       14      Murcia  1283.0           500.0   84.0   
890  2020-04-06       15     Navarra  3355.0          1488.0  124.0   
891  2020-04-06       16  País Vasco  9021.0          4856.0  417.0   
892  2020-04-06       17    La Rioja  2846.0           918.0   66.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you mean by "sum this categories". I'm assuming you mean that for each date, you want to sum the values across all different regions to come up with the total values for Spain?

In which case, you will want to `groupby` date, then `.sum()` the columns (you can drop the `States` category.

```py
grouped_df = df.groupby("date")["Cases", "Deaths", ...].sum()
grouped_df.set_index("date").plot()
```

This snippet will probably not work directly, you may need to reformat the dates etc. But should be enough to get you started.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean but still can't get the graph to work. Getting this error TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `groupby` followed by a cumsum not including dates.

```
columns_to_group = ['Cases', 'Deaths', 
                  'Recoveries', 'Critical', 'Hospitalized', 'date']
new_columns = ['Cases_sum', 'Deaths_sum', 
               'Recoveries_sum', 'Critical_sum', 'Hospitalized_sum']

df_grouped = df[columns_to_group].groupby('date').sum().reset_index()
```

For plotting seaborn provides an easy functions:

```
import seaborn as sns

df_melted = df_grouped.melt(id_vars=["date"])
sns.lineplot(data=df_melted, x='date', y = 'value', hue='variable')
```

Comment: This actually worked thanks a lot! Could you help me do this but instead of separated by state the total for Spain.

Comment: Group by date, see the edit, now if you need all the plots in the same figure, better not to use seaborn but datframe built int plot.

Comment: Not really getting it is there any way to message you?

Comment: No, because you are new in the forum, I made a change to save the data into a new dataframe, that should work as the previous answer was incorrect.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but im lost and couldn't get the edit to work. What I need is to show how cases,deaths,recovered have increased as time increases.

Comment: Post the error, and let me know if 1) the `df_grouped` is actually having data and cumulative data by date, and 2) if you need all plots in the same plot

Comment: Is it posible to have all those values in just one line for the total instead of separating them? The error I get is : Could not interpret input 'Fecha'

Comment: Also df_grouped should not be cummulative only summed. Thanks !

Comment: Check the edit and let me know if that is working, make sure the `df_group` has the column `Fecha`.

Comment: This worked perfectly you are genius! If you have time I need help on something else i'll leave it below.

Comment: The data is divided my 'States' and now I need to compare the same things you just got to the totals of a state 'Navarra'.

Comment: It is better create another question and mark this one as resolved